# Delete a KEY Name in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have something like this.

```
"data": {
        "abcd": [
            {
                "abc": {
                    "fr": "India",
                    "to": "Moon",
                }
            },
            {
                "abc": {
                    "fr": "Mars",
                    "to": "Jupiter",
                }
            }
        ],
        "distance": 1234,
    }
```

But I want to convert to something like this

```
"data": {
            "abcd": [
                {

                        "fr": "India",
                        "to": "Moon",
                },
                {

                        "fr": "Mars",
                        "to": "Jupiter",

                }
            ],
            "distance": 1234,
        }
```

I want to brign the details inside the abc object and make them as an unnamed object inside the abcd array of objects.

Please help out with this.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: add the code in question

Comment: @Aneek so to delete a key, you tried push?

Comment: Loop through abcd. Copy abc's children. Delete abc. Assign the children to where abc was. These are the steps, the code is not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#map` to iterate the array and return the contents of the `abc` key of each object. Assign the results to `obj.data.abcd`:

```js
const obj = {"data":{"abcd":[{"abc":{"fr":"India","to":"Moon"}},{"abc":{"fr":"Mars","to":"Jupiter"}}],"distance":1234}};

obj.data.abcd = obj.data.abcd.map((o) => o.abc);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `reduce()` will suffice

```js
let obj = {
  "data": {
    "abcd": [{
        "abc": {
          "fr": "India",
          "to": "Moon",
        }
      },
      {
        "abc": {
          "fr": "Mars",
          "to": "Jupiter",
        }
      }
    ],
    "distance": 1234,
  }
};

obj.data.abcd = obj.data.abcd.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b.abc), []);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It's a good answer but please don't spoon feed - otherwise SO becomes a coding service, and everyone will post first-time questions with little to know research or effort.

Comment: whats the problem with that?

Comment: As the OP is unlikely to understand what you've written, may you add a simple explanation as to what your code does?